# number of elements in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given that $k$ is a finite field with $q$ elements and $V$ is a $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space, then by basis representation, we know that for $v \in V, v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_nv_n$ uniquely. Therefore there is $q^n-1$ non zero vectors in $V$(because $0_V=0v_1+\cdots+0v_n$). But on the other hand, we can also says there are $q-1$ choices for $a_1$, $q-1$ choices for $a_2$ and so on. Hence there are $(q-1)^n$ non zero vectors in $V$. But that is absurd because $q^n-1 \not= (q-1)^n$ in general. So what's wrong with my deduction? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your second calculation doesn't allow for vectors of the form $v = a_1v_1 + 0v_2 + \dots 0v_n$, where $a_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: oh i see! i'm such a moron...

Comment: No you're not. It is a very good question and it is encouraging to see that you checked your second expression for the number of non-zero vectors agreed with the first one you found.